# Error when uploading to FTP (PHP)

Tags: php, html, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to an FTP using the following:

```
    $ftp_server="***********"; 
 $ftp_user_name="*********"; 
 $ftp_user_pass="************"; 
 $file = $path;//tobe uploaded 
 $remote_file = "/htdocs/site2/telemessages/en/".$_SESSION['dir']; 

// set up basic connection 
 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password 
 $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

  //upload a file 
 if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) { 
  echo "successfully uploaded $file\n"; 
    exit; 
 } else { 
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n"; 
    exit; 
    } 
 // close the connection 
 ftp_close($conn_id)
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

http://puu.sh/3EiVO.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to upload a file but calling it a directory. Make sure `$_SESSION['dir']` contains a valid filename that is acceptable on the remote server

Comment: What is the the values for $file and $remote_file

Comment: thanks for the feedback  
$_SESSION = birthdays/Child/  
therefore $remote_file = /htdocs/site2/telemessages/en/birthdays/Child/  

-$file = 1794 - Happy Birthday father-in-law.mp3

$file is from a form with input type form, but i understand because of security you can't actually store the full path!?  
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change permission of folder that you want to upload file  to it
You can use chmod 777 for that